# EclipseLink - reload metadata

Tags: eclipselink

Is there a way to reload EclipseLink metadata in runtime? I wanted to either call some REST that would serve „eclipselink-orm.xml” file - similar to METADATA_SOURCE_XML_URL or somehow refresh that metamodel programmatically - is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering own question:

```
 refreshMetamodel()
```

method from `JpaEntityManagerFactory` class does the job.